# Is setTimeout a part of JavaScript it self or it is just an api that the browser provides?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, v8

Is setTimeout a part of JavaScript it self or it is just an api that the browser provides ?

Is it a part of ES ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Specifications):

> **Specification**
>   WHATWG HTML Living Standard

… and you won't see it in [ECMA-262 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).

Comment: What is the difference between  WHATWG and ECMA?

Answer (score 16):

The [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function is actually exposed by the browser's `window` object as as such they aren't necessarily defined in the ECMAScript specification because they're not JavaScript features, they are features of the browser itself.

You can see from the specification section in the previously linked documentation that it uses the **WHATWG HTML Living Standard** :

[image]

As opposed to a Javascript function like [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Specifications) that explicitly uses **EMACScript** :

[image]

Comment: Vote up, it is a very helpful answer. But unfortunately it is not the first correct answer to my specific question.

Comment: _" exposed by the browser's window object as as such ... they're not JavaScript features, they are features of the browser itself"_ Everything defined by the ECMAScript standard is exposed by `window` as well. And JavaScript is sometimes defined as ECMAScript + environment APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the `window` object in the browser, not defined in ECMAScript. Therefore, other environments such as Node are not guaranteed to have it.

Comment: Clarification: while it is true that any arbitrary ECMAScript-compliant environment could possibly not have `setTimeout`, Node.js in particular [*is* guaranteed to have it](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg).

Comment: @apsillers However, note that the Node.js implementation differs from the web one. It returns an object instead of a number.